# Will an ignored signal still interrupt a syscall under Linux?

Tags: linux, signals

Let's say I `SIG_IGN` `SIGPIPE` at the start of my program. Later, I receive a `SIGPIPE`. **Normally**, some syscall such as `select()` that was active at the time the signal was received will be interrupted and will return failure and set `errno = EINTR`. My question is, does this happen if I explictly tell the Linux Kernel I want to ignore `SIGPIPE`?

Answer (score 0):

No. It will just ignore it. The only signal that cannot be ignored is SIGKILL.